# Take photo, display photo thumbnail in new activity upon success

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

Right now I've got an app that takes a photo via an intent. After taking the photo, I want the user to be able to confirm it and push the photo to another activity where they can add details. I'm struggling to find the correct way to pass the photo from activity to activity.

Right now, confirming the photo brings the user back to the main activity.

Here's my relevant code:

Main Activity

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    Log.d("MySecondApp",fileUri.toString());// create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data!=null) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MySecondApp");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MySecondApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new     java.util.Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like

```
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    handleCameraPhoto(data);
```

handle method:

```
private void handleCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", mImageBitmap);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and then, retrieve it in your other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

and assign it to your ImageView

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: this was nearly the solution, I just had to make `ImageView` a member-field. So, `mImageView iv = (ImageView)...`. Then you need to declare the constant `private ImageView mImageView`. Thanks for getting me there though!

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor in your new class that takes an intent or even the image:

```
class newClass {
    public newClass(Intent intent){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then just make the intent the size of a thumbnail in this new class where you can do the confirmation in a popup or something similar and then have the information to be filled on the page for this class.  This will also be better because if they wanted to retake the picture you could have this class which they are taken to after the picture is taken if not accepted go to take another picture.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to take a full size image and a thumbnail version as well:

[Use Camera Activity for Thumbnail and Full Size Image](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590)

after you did that you can extract the file path of the saved file from the file instance using g`etAbsolutePath()` method and pass it to the following `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! Could you give me an idea of how to implement `getAbsolutePath()` along with the rest of the thumbnail code?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you have trouble with?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to pass the photo along to another view after it's saved and all. I'm guessing I should use `getAbsolutePath` to do that, but I'm not sure how to put the rest of it into code cause I still suck at java. Do you have any idea of how to write it out?